# C# Dereference of a possibly null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I'm somewhat confused by the warning I'm getting. Here is the relevant code:

```
#nullable enable
public partial class FileTable<TItem> : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    // bunch of class code

    public async Task FilterColumn(Func<TItem, IComparable>? itemProperty, string? searchString)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ViewItems);

        if (itemProperty == null)
            return;

        if (searchString == null)
            searchString = string.Empty;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in ViewItems)
            {
                var property = itemProperty(item.Item);

                if (property == null)
                    continue;

                item.IsVisible = property.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower());
            }
        });
        StateHasChanged();
    } 
}
```

I'm getting the warning for `property.ToString()` As you can see I have already added a bunch of null-checks, but none seems to get rid of the warning. As far as I can see it is impossible for `property` to be `null` at the this point. Obviously I'm missing something...so what could be triggering this warning?

Comment: Is it rather complaining that `ToString()` might return `null`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `property`, and the return type of `itemProperty()`?

Comment: @gunr2171 Question is already solved, but for clarification: the whole class is code-behind for a custom `table` component, which should take a collection of any type and add additional funcionality such as sorting and filtering. I use `itemProperty()` to search the property of the corresponding column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `ToString()` can return `null`; it is bad practice, but: it can:

```cs
namespace System
{
    public class Object
    {
        // ...
        public virtual string? ToString();
        // ...
    }
}
```

the error goes away if you rule that out:

```cs
var s = property.ToString() ?? "";
item.IsVisible = s.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower());
```

Note also that it is more efficient to use a comparison that ignores case, rather than forcing additional string allocations:

```cs
item.IsVisible = s.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Will mark the answer as soon as possible

Comment: @RolandDeschain see also the edit (last line)

Comment: Btw, thanks for the note on ignoring cases :)